# Python websocket client send in run loop

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket

I'm piping `stdin` to a websocket using [websocket-client](https://github.com/liris/websocket-client/). I'm connecting to the websocket like this:

```
ws = WebSocketApp('ws://example.com/websocket')
ws.run_forever(ping_interval=15)
```

`run_forever` starts an infinite loop. I'd like to simultaneously read from `sys.stdin` like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        ws.send(line)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

    if not line:
        break
```

Is there a way to alternate between the two loops with threading? Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

This could probably be done with Tornado or Twisted, but I'd rather keep the dependencies at a minimum if there's a way to do it with the standard lib.

Comment: what happens when you enter  something?

Comment: Currently, `ws.run_forever()` is the last line that runs. It never reaches the second loop

Comment: What is the difference between `WebSocketApp` and `create_connection`?

Comment: WebSocketApp has a builtin keep alive ping (this is what needs to run infinitely, it pings the server every 15 seconds)

Comment: Instead of using WebSocketApp and run_forever, I could use my own loop that runs `ws.ping()` every 15 seconds. Still have the problem of two loops though

Comment: http://pastebin.com/r8JJby2K based on the example in the docs

Comment: No worries, to break you might want to add `if not line.strip()` but you will probable need to  `ws.close()` if  want the code to end